# Can you detect meta-data in service?

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it possible to detect the meta-data in service?

I would like to have a few services in a Manifest (I am doing multiple watch faces for Android Wear), and wondering whether it is possible to have 2 or more services uses the same code, but pass in different meta data (for example, one is black, one is white - each which its own watch faces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would not work, because you would register the same component (said `Service`) twice. If you have a component registered twice and you send an explicit `Intent` to call it, which of those would be called?

There are alternatives, that would allow you to achieve what you want:

1. Have a base `Service` class and two subclasses that have either white or black background.
2. *Recommended*: have just one watch face and add configuration activity. For simple things like changing the background, the configuration can be on the watch. For more complex things have use Phone side configuration.

This is a sample of a Phone side config activity: http://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/Application/src/com.example.android.wearable.watchface/DigitalWatchFaceCompanionConfigActivity.html

You can download the whole sample and take a look how configuration is implemented.